# Writing Scheduler/RTOS in XC8

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, microchip, xc8

I have an interest in writing a scheduler/RTOS project in XC8 using an enhanced MCU with access to the hardware stack.

I am trying to figure out how to control the creation of the software stacks so each tasks software stack will get a certain range in the general purpose ram.
Conceptually this is all easy to program in ASM but I want to be able to write C programs and have the software stacks for each task be put into the right address space.

There doesn't appear to be an option to create a separate software stack for a certain section of code or even create multiple software stacks - how do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Multiple stacks are something your task setup and task switch code would typically have to manually manage.  You are unlikely to find an IDE wizard for it, unless you are using an RTOS that the IDE has integrated support for, but since you are crafting your own, this would be your responsibility entirely.  It sounds like you may need to do a little more reading on how operating systems work and a little more planning on how you want to manage memory generally.

Comment: By default the C compiler creates either a compiled stack or software stack and locates it at a certain area. If I want to write anything in C I need to control the function of the software stack manually...

Comment: At a crude level, you can allocate a block of memory of requested size when each task starts, initialize the stack pointer there before making the initial call to each task, and then include the stack pointer along with the registers saved in each context switch by the scheduler.  But as with most things, the hard part is in the details - can you protect that stacks from each other or other overruns, where to allocate them in the first place, etc - these things have been contemplated and debated for generations.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed the compiler would not allow me to directly manipulate the stack pointer(it's not completely clear to me where the software-stacks stack pointer is even located or how to adjust it). My goal isn't to prevent memory contamination or anything but just implement a simple scheduler assuming each software stack will be sub 250 bytes. In addition I am having some trouble finding what other registers need to be saved during a context switch as it appears the compiler uses additional registers.

Comment: To do any of this, you will need to understand what the compiler does behind the scenes while compiling your code. Some of the things you seem to be attributing to it are not the compiler per se, but rather the *startup code* it may insert by default - the distinction is that only runs once, and you can subsequently override it, while anything it inserts while compiling your code may be repeated during execution. Typically there are pragmas or options you can set to control much of this. It's unlikely you will accomplish your project without spending time contemplating disassembly!